# Custom ComboBox doesn't select with mouse?

Tags: javafx-8

I couldn't find anything on this - so I wanted to post a simple question.  I want to create a custom ComboBox that displays a combination of the fields in when extended.  The code below correctly displays my list, and reacts to keyboard arrows, but when I select the arrow from the dropdown, the list has no reaction to the mouse click for selection.

[EDIT]Also - I can't seem to get type ahead working on this either.

I am not sure what I am missing.

```
public class JavaFXApplication7 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Person> cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.setCellFactory(column -> new ListCell<Person>() {
            private HBox graphic = new HBox();
            private Label label1 = new Label() ;
            private Label label2 = new Label(" || ");
                private Label label3 = new Label();                
                {
                    graphic.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3);
                }
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                if (person == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    label1.setText(person.firstName.get());
                        label3.setText(person.email.get());
                    setGraphic(graphic);
                }
            }
        });

        ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Person p = new Person();
        p.email.set("foo@bar.com");
        p.firstName.set("Tony");
        p.lastName.set("Stark");
        p.phone.set("(555) 555-1212");

        items.add(p);
         Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.email.set("foo@bar.com");
        p2.firstName.set("Bruce");
        p2.lastName.set("Wayne");
        p2.phone.set("(444) 444-1212");

        items.add(p2);

        cb.setItems(items);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(cb);        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class Person {
        StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty phone = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        @Override
        public String toString () {
            return firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing

```
super.updateItem(person, empty);
```

in the `updateItem` method.